# Adding Headline and Text for Facebook Video Ads on API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Power editor allows you to add other fields like headline, and text, but the api is only limited to description for video ads. I tried to create a slideshow with a combination of images.
I actually tried, and it spins up error if I add the message, or caption field. Why is there a difference in the behaviour of power editor and api? Am I doing something wrong on my end?
The ad created via the api, with the empty fields on power editor.
Facebook official doc on video data -: 
https://developers.facebook.com/…/r…/ad-creative-video-data/

Comment: Yes, there are many differences between the API and the functionality PE provides. They are not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was to add a 'link_description' on the CALL_TO_ACTION value array (using a 'Learn More' CALL_TO_ACTION type).

My video data object looks like:

```
[
    'title' => 'ADS HEADING',
    'description' => 'ADS TEXT',
    'image_url' => <URL TO IMAGE>,
    'video_id' => <VIDEO_ID>,
    'call_to_action' => [
        'type' => 'LEARN_MORE',
        'value' => [
            'link' => <LINK>,
            'link_caption' => <URL_CAPTION>,
            'link_description' => 'ADS DESCRIPTION',
        ]
    ] 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `name`, `title`(only in video ad creatives), `description`.